# Is there a way to define a class reference on an interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface, abstract-class

Say I have an interface with a generic reference to a class that extends some other interface.

```java
public interface Foo<S extends Bar> {


}
```

and that I have some abstract class that implements that interface

```java
public abstract class Baz<S extends Bar> {

}
```

In this abstract class I want to introspect on what S is and create an empty S class so I can look at its fields and do something with that information.

How can I make it so a class extending this abstract class with some signature can hold some reference to the S class so that I can instantiate an instance of that in the abstract Baz class?

I originally thought I would be able to make an overridable subclass in the interface, but this does not seem to be possible.

I also am fairly sure that I cannot just figure this out from S itself because of type erasure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First you need a abstract getter which returns a instance of S or Class<S> in your Baz class. Then you can use reflection to create instances of that class, inspect and change them.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you just want to declare a field `S s;`? Do you want to create a `class Foo extends Baz<Inner>{ static class Inner extends Bar {}}`?

Comment: Actually you do not even know the class, because you're assumption about type erasure is wrong in this case. Looking at TypeReference of the Jackson Library (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java) we can see that the Type of T can be resolved. This works because Subclasses of a generic class keep their type information, which can then be read.